# If $u_{k|_{\Omega}} \to u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $(u_k) \subset C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $u_k \to u $ in $W^{1,p}(\bar{\Omega})$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have already proven that for every $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $1 \leq p < \infty$  and every open set of class $C^1$ there exists a sequence $(u_k) \subset C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that  $u_{k|_{\Omega}} \to u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

I am now curious if this implies that $u_k \in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega}) $ and converges to $u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, due to the fact that $\Omega $ is $C^1$.

Comment: In general, if $\Omega$ is also bounded, this is not true, in other words $C^\infty_{c}(\Omega)$ is not dense in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $\Omega \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @JohnMartin I know $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is not dense in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, but what I need is to conclude that $(u_n)$ is in $C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$.

Comment: Yes, I'm just saying that if $\Omega$ is also bounded, then essentially $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega}) = C_{c}^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: But elements in $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ are zero at the boundary of $\Omega$, which is not the case of $C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$, or maybe you mean elements of $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ restricted to $\Omega$

Comment: for this I wrote "essentially", the rest is in the sense that $\overline{\Omega}$ is a compact set. However, it is just an observation, in fact I did not answer the question

Comment: Could you explain it a little bit?

Comment: But I do not know, unless of functions that are zero on boundary, we have effectively $C_{c}^\infty(\Omega)=C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$? maybe this could be a starting point for a counterexample, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think that what I need to conclude is that for every $u_k \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we say that $u_n \in C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$